# Install Windows 10 on SATA SSD

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd

My SSD isn't getting recognized by the Windows 10 installer.

I'm installing from a USB using the official installation creator.

Here are the steps I've already taken:

1) Used `DISKPART` to clean and create a `NTFS` partition on the drive. It is listed when using `SHIFT+F10` -> `LIST DISK`. The partition has been set to `ACTIVE`.

2) Downloaded a load of drivers from the motherboard's website and browsed and tried those when asked. After I click the `next` button is just says no drivers were found, and the cycle continues.

3) Tried various USB ports for the installer.

4) Set the SSD to both `SATA` and `IDE` modes in the BIOS.

My motherboard is an [ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_EVO_R20/).

As I try other methods I think of/try I'll update this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38715/discussion-on-question-by-rhughes-install-windows-10-on-sata-ssd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now successfully installed Windows 10.

I had to first install and activate Windows 8 (Windows 7 would also have worked) and then ran the USB created by the official installation creator from there. I selected the 'Keep Nothing' option which allowed a clean install, and followed the prompts respectively.